# How to blink the red colour of RGB led

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

Here Is my code details of RGB blink of raspberry-pi

blue and green blinking but red one not working I have also try exchange the gpio pin but i got same result

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
red_pin = 18
green_pin = 23
blue_pin = 24
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(red_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(green_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blue_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.output(red_pin, False)
GPIO.output(green_pin, False)
GPIO.output(blue_pin, False)
try:         
   while True:
       UserInput = input()
       UserInput = str(User)
       if UserInput == "red":
            GPIO.output(red_pin, True)
            GPIO.output(green_pin, False)
            GPIO.output(blue_pin, False)
       elif UserInput == "green":
            GPIO.output(red_pin, False)
            GPIO.output(green_pin, True)
            GPIO.output(blue_pin, False)
       elif UserInput == "blue":
            GPIO.output(red_pin, False)
            GPIO.output(green_pin, False)
            GPIO.output(blue_pin, True)
       else:
           print("Only red, green, and blue are valid colors.")
finally:  
  print("Cleaning up.")
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Do you have another red LED you can try with? To perhaps make sure that it also isn't the led itself that's busted

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, really. Try another LED - which you have, and that seems to be working.

Are you using a resistor?
Because all i can gather is that you have managed to blow the red part of the RGB LED.